# Variable inside shell_exec

Tags: php, variables, shell-exec

I am total noob in scripting, and try to find out where is the problem in my code. I have a text files with customer details, first line of the file is username, second is real name. This details i need to pass to php. First, I need to find oldest file in directory. I created bash script which returns customer username:

```
oldest=`ls -tr1 temp/data/*.details|head -1`
head -n1 $oldest
```

This finds odest file (temp/data/xxx.details) and returns username, let's say xxx.

Now, to the php:

```
$username = shell_exec('./oldest_order.sh');
$name = shell_exec('head -2 temp/data/'.$username.'.details | sed -n 2p');
```

I can get username in my php, with the first line: it's xxx, but second line does not work, However, if I change '.$username.' to xxx, it works, so problem is somewhere around this variable.

Please advice.

Comment: Perhaps a new-line or space at the end or the beginning? Does a `var_dump($username);` give you the correct length of the string. If it is white-space, you can use `'.trim($username).'`

Comment: `var_dump($username)` would confirm that. it'd be `string(3)` for `xxx` without a line break, and 4 or 5 for xxx WITH cr/lf

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer, jeroen. `var_dump($username);` gives me `string(17) "xxx "` This line does contain space between First and last name. Newline symbols (ctrl-m) has been replaced previously with `sed 's/.$//'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, what is the relation between First Name, Last Name and the username? And is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is a new-line or space at the end or the beginning.

You can check that by doing a `var_dump($username);`. That will give you the actual length of the string so that you can compare it with the length you think it should have.

If it is white-space at the beginning or the end, you can use:

```
$name = shell_exec('head -2 temp/data/'.trim($username).'.details | sed -n 2p');
```

Comment: OK, figured out. i had string(17), for the line contains only 16 characters. `trim` does the job. Thanks for help!